# Checks if 'frodo' can be 'fr*d*'

Tags: python

The code below,

part is one of `('frodo', 'fradi'), ('frodo', 'crodo'), ('frodo', 'abc123'), ('frodo', 'abc123'), ('frodo', 'frodoc'), ('fradi', 'crodo'), ('fradi', 'abc123'), ('fradi', 'abc123'), ('fradi', 'frodoc'), ('crodo', 'abc123')`.

ban_group is `["fr*d*", "abc1**"]`

Function solution checks if part[i] can be ban_group[i].

What I expected was

when part is ('frodo', 'fradi'), part[0] can be ban_group[0] and part[1] can't be ban_group[1]. So it's False.

when part is ('frodo', 'abc123'), part[0] can be ban_group[0] and part[1] can be ban_group[1]. So it's True, so add part to list candidates.

But it doesn't work as I expected. I really don't get what part is problem.

Can you help me with this?

```
from itertools import combinations

def check_id(user, ban):
    for i in range(len(ban)):
        if ban[i] == '*':
            continue
        elif user[i] != ban[i]:
            return False
    return True

candidates = []
def solution(user_group, ban_group):
    for part in combinations(user_group, len(ban_group)):
        for i in range(len(part)):
            if check_id(part[i], ban_group[i]) is True:
                candidates.append(part)
    return candidates

print(solution(["frodo", "fradi", "crodo", "abc123", "frodoc"], ["fr*d*", "abc1**"]))
```

Comment: Did you try to verify that `check_id` gives the right answers, before worrying about `solution`?

Comment: "But it doesn't work as I expected. I really don't get what part is problem." What happens, and how is that different from what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

In this fragment:

```
        for i in range(len(part)):
            if check_id(part[i], ban_group[i]) is True:
                candidates.append(part)
```

you append `part` to `candidates` if **any** item in `part` passed `check_id`. I think you wanted to do it only if **all** items in `part` passed `check_id`. So, the correct thing to do is:

```
        if all(check_id(part[i], ban_group[i]) for i in range(len(part))):
            candidates.append(part)
```

BTW, Karl Knechtel is right about `check_id` function - it is not correct either, just see what `check_id('frodoc', 'fr*d*')` does.

Comment: Can I ask you why it can be 'any'? if i iterate 0 to 2, I thought this function pass in only (part[0], ban_group[0]), (part[1], ban_group[1]). cause i works identically in part and ban_group at the same time. If it's kind of any, does it mean it pass (part[0], ban_group[1]) too?

Answer (score 0):

```
    for i in range(len(part)):
        if check_id(part[i], ban_group[i]) is True:
            candidates.append(part)
```

This will compare each element from `part` to *the corresponding* element of `ban_group`, and `append` the entire `part` to `candidates` for *each* element that matched.

What you want (if I understood you correctly) is to check each element from `part` against *the entire* `ban_group`, to see if any of the `ban_group` elements matched. Then you need to look at those results and see if *all* of the `part` elements matched, and possibly `append` *once* to the candidates.

It can be tricky to do this work with `for` loops, and takes a lot of code for a simple idea. Much better is to use the built-in `any` and `all` functions, which can be passed a generator expression in order to process an entire list easily. Then you can use functions to name each step of the process. For the overall loop, we can also use a list comprehension instead of `append`ing each result to a new list.

```
def is_banned(user, ban_group):
    # use `any` to see if the user matches any of the ban patterns.
    return any(check_id(user, ban) for ban in ban_group)

def all_banned(part, ban_group):
    # use `all` to see if all of the users matched a ban pattern.
    return all(is_banned(user, ban_group) for user in part)

def solution(user_group, ban_group):
    # apply the `all_banned` logic to each combination of users of the
    # specified size.
    return [
        part for part in combinations(user_group, len(ban_group))
        if all_banned(part, ban_group)
    ]
```

I hope I correctly understand the intended logic. If not, it should be easy enough to fix, using similar technique.

Comment: It occurred to me, maybe you *did* want to compare a given user to a corresponding ban pattern. For this purpose, the built-in `zip` is helpful - see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel . However, be careful if the order matters - notice the difference between `itertools.combinations` and `itertools.permutations`.

Comment: Thanks so much. It's really helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand currectly, You want to append a `part` to `candidate = []` only if all element of matches with their co-respondend position element in ban group. But in your code you are appending `part` to `candidate` if any one of those element matched not both of them.
That's why I have use a `flag` to keep track if all of the element in `part` matched.

```
from itertools import combinations
def check_id(user, ban):
    for i in range(len(ban)):
        if ban[i] == '*':
            continue
        elif user[i] != ban[i]:
            return False
    return True

candidates = []
def solution(user_group, ban_group):
    for part in combinations(user_group, len(ban_group)):
        flag = True
        for i in range(len(part)):
            flag = flag and check_id(part[i], ban_group[i])
        if flag:
            candidates.append(part)
    return candidates

print(solution(["frodo", "fradi", "crodo", "abc123", "frodoc"], ["fr*d*", "abc1**"]))
```